# Разбор XML. Снова

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmlparser, plsql

Привет всем. Есть код в XMLtype() oracle:

```
<p:Parameters>
<p:Param label="Label1" name="00001">
    <p:Regexp>Regexp1</p:Regexp>
</p:Param>
<p:Param label="label2" name="00002">
    <p:Regexp>Regexp1</p:Regexp>
</p:Param>
</p:Parameters>
```

Как вытащить значение атрибута **name** во второй ноде?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
select 
  extract(struct(i), '//*:Parameters/*:Param[@name="00002"]/@name').getstringval() s_att_name
    into param_att
 from dual;
```

Но **param_att** is null. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос выглядит нормально, отрабатывает так как нужно. Проверьте значение struct(i), по всей видимости туда пришло что-то отличное от указанной вами XML.

```
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3      select xmltype(
  4              '<p:Params xmlns:p="http://schemaurl.org/XMLSchema">
  5                  <p:Parameters>
  6                      <p:Param label="Label1" name="00001">
  7                          <p:Regexp>Regexp1</p:Regexp>
  8                      </p:Param>
  9                      <p:Param label="label2" name="00002">
 10                          <p:Regexp>Regexp1</p:Regexp>
 11                      </p:Param>
 12                  </p:Parameters>
 13              </p:Params>') as val
 14        from dual
 15  )
 16  select
 17    extract(val, '//*:Parameters/*:Param[@name="00002"]@name').getstringval() s_att_name
 18   from t
 19  /

S_ATT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

00002

SQL>
```

Comment: Код действительно корректен, просто я криворокий и какосячил с неймспейсами) в struct(i) все правильно содержится, а ns у меня в XPath был кривой! Спасибо за ответ!